# Is there a quick way to find out which updates are going to be installed before hitting the shutdown button with the exclamation mark?

Tags: windows-7, automatic-update

I have the feeling, that since last patch day Windows update too often offered the installation of an update. Including that oft Windows 7 sp 1 without checking, that I do not have sufficient place on the C: partition and I don't want it to be installed without being asked and prepared.

Is there a quick way to check which updates are going to be installed when I hit the shutdown button?

**Edit:**

Despite I unmarked SP1. After shutdown I see a further attempt of Sp1 which fails with Error Code   800F0828 which means it has lrecognized that it has not enough diskspace.

Is there any way to stop this so called 'important update' from trying to install itself?

Comment: Is there any reason not to just free up a bit of space and set it going?  I had little to no disturbance on two machines with the update and at least it's done with then, while they were being used it started, then a sometime later I restarted them to install...

Comment: It's a notebook with many installed programs where there is only 2 GB on C: left and reorganizing would be real work.

Comment: Freed diskand installed update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so, use "Windows Update" and review the marked items.

Comment: It's sp1 again. I unmarked it multiple times.

Comment: You should be able to hide the updates you don't want, if I remember.